# Give wx.StaticBitmap a transparent background? wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have an image that has a white background, how can I make this background invisible?
Its in a wx.StaticBitmap

```
wx.StaticBitmap(self, bitmap=wx.Bitmap('images/myimage.png'),pos=(0,0))
```

Comment: I suggest you just edit your image to fit your needs. I think it's more an image editing question.

Answer (score 1):

By invisible, I assume you mean transparent so that whatever is behind the image shines through.

This is not a function of widgets, but whatever you use to edit your image.  You don't say!

I use microsoft visual studio.  Here's a screenshot.  Notice how the background, shown in a sort of blue-green in the editor - this will show up as transparent, which you can see happening in the column showing the fianl appearances.

[image]