# wxWidgets Transparent control with transparent bitmap

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets

I'm having transparent control ( a custom control with paint and erase background event ) on top of a transparent frame and i'm trying to draw a transparent png to the centre of the control without any luck.

What i'm getting is an image with black rectangle as background!. please see the attached screenshot and download source code Test.zip  from the link http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=35465

Is there any way we can draw png file with transparency?

Thanks in advance
Rajan.M

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image from png to bitmap, then set the required background bits to transparent.

IMHO, the easiest way to force the background of a bitmap to be transparent is to use your favourite bitmap editor.  I use the one that comes with Visual studio, see this answer [Give wx.StaticBitmap a transparent background? wxpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684388/give-wx-staticbitmap-a-transparent-background-wxpython/9684977#9684977)

Comment: converted png to bitmap and able to iterate the raw data using wxPixelData and altered all alpha values to 0  but again i got black background wihtout image.i'm using wxGCDC.

Comment: i'm having png with transparency. please use the link i've provided to download the sample soure and png file.

Comment: @rajan_m Sorry, I do not understand your comment.

Comment: the png image i'm using is created with adobe photo shop with the transparent background.

Comment: OK.  You can now convert the image from png to bitmap using just about any image editor.  I like irfanview.  http://www.irfanview.ca/

Comment: @ravnespoint i have a image created using an editor with transparent backgroud. when i try to draw the image using wxdc in a control whose parent is opaque its coming good. but when i try to draw in a control whose parent is transparent i'm getting the black background. i think i'm clear now.